# DB2 has a default Database named "sample", when I am trying to run command connect to sample, it is not able to connect

Tags: database, command-line, db2, backend, sample

DB2 has a default Database named "sample", when I am trying to run command "CONNECT TO SAMPLE", it is saying "SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "SAMPLE" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705" in command line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBcLU.png)

I am trying to run command "CONNECT TO SAMPLE", it is saying "SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "SAMPLE" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705" in command line. I was expecting it to connect to the default database named "SAMPLE"

Comment: How did you verify that the SAMPLE database exists on the database-server?  Are you running the interactive-CLP directly on the hostname that also runs the database-server?   IMPROVE your question by editing it.

Comment: Db2 does _not_ have any default databases; it would have the database called SAMPLE only after someone had created it.

Comment: run db2sampl to create it - if this command reports that the database already exists  please update your question